# In the US, can a person openly refuse to obey regulations that have been ruled to be against the law?

Tags: texas, covid-19, regulations

As an  example, some school districts in Texas are [openly disobeying](https://www.texastribune.org/2021/12/01/texas-mask-mandate-ban-public-schools/) the ban on mandatory masking in schools, which [was recently confirmed](https://www.texastribune.org/2021/12/01/texas-mask-mandate-ban-public-schools/) to be legal by a Federal appellate court. So we have a situation where:

1. State regulation (via the governors executive order) says masking cannot be mandated in schools
2. Courts have so far confirmed that the executive order is completely legal
3. School district officials are openly defying the law by mandating masks in their jurisdiction

Does this mean that any student is entitled to openly refuse to obey the masking rules, citing the legal situation above? Or are they expected to comply until a court explicitly rules that their *particular* school district is violating the law?

Comment: Relatedly: would a student punished for violating such a rule have any recourse?

Comment: This is going to depend on the particulars.  For example, how is the school district reacting to students who openly refuse to comply?  School authorities are closest to the students and their behavior.  If the student is legally entitled to disobey the school, and the school nonetheless enforces its rules, the student has little choice but to comply in the short term while suing the school district.  Even if the student prevails, how does the state judiciary or executive react to the school's disobedience?

Comment: @RyanM that's basically my question. I'm assuming the legal advice would be to openly disobey, request to be officially asked to vacate school premises, then sue the school and ask a judge to force the school to do otherwise?